# If you shake this sphere with sand for $n$ times ($n$ could be as large as you want), will the sand come back to its original arrangement?

Tags: thermodynamics, probability, poincare-recurrence

"According to the Poincaré theorem, the sand will eventually come back to its original arrangement after a large number of shakes. But based on intuitive thinking, if you shake it well, the sand would never and ever come back to its original arrangement. What am I missing?"

[image]

Comment: Just use the infinite monkey theorem and approximate a "shake" as something which chooses a random configuration.

Comment: The initial state is one possible state out of the trillions of possible sand states. There is a non-zero probability that a shake will return it to its initial state but it's not an eventuality. You may have to shake for 1000s of years before it occurs.

Comment: This is obviously false as stated because it's possible, for example, that shake one yields a new configuration which in turn is left unchanged by all subsequent shakes.

Comment: @ConnorBehan so you mean you could make the sand particles can come back to its original arrangment by shaking it a lot of times.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban why do I feel that even after trillions of years of shaking, the sand is still well blended?

Comment: Depending on the number of sand particles, you may have to shake longer than the age of the sun. It's a very, very, small probability but not zero

Comment: It's a combinatorics problem. This should help:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448/in-how-many-different-ways-can-i-sort-balls-of-two-different-colors

Comment: @StevanV.Saban I understand all the probability and combinator, but I still have the feeling that if you shake it as long as you want, you will never make the sand come back to its original state (red and blue apart)

Comment: "if you shake it well, the sand would never and ever come back to its original arrangement. What am I missing?" - it'll never happen, but it's not technically impossible, just very very very ... very very unlikely. Suppose that instead of sand, you have 4 marbles inside, 2 blue, 2 red, all mixed up; it's not hard to imagine that after some amount of shaking, the marbles will group together, blue ones on one side, red ones on the other. Suppose you had 6, or 8, or 10 marbles: it becomes more and more unlikely; with 100, 500, 1000 marbles, it's *incredibly* unlikely.

Comment: "based on intuitive thinking" - our intuition is based on our limited experience of how everyday objects behave over quite short timescales. This is not a reliable guide in science, and especially not in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you shake long enough, the odds get better and better that it will return to its original configuration. But that may take way more shakes than your intuition is prepared to deal with.

It also depends on what you mean by original configuration.

Suppose you mean by original configuration nothing more than all the blue grains are on the left and all the red grains are on the right. Suppose there a 1000 grains of sand. Suppose a shake completely randomizes the sand. Each grain has a probability of $1/2$ or $2^{-1}$ of being on the correct side. The odds of all being correct is $2^{-1000}$. On the average, you would expect the original configuration every $2^{1000}$ shakes. That is roughly $1$ followed by $300$ or so $0$'s. If the universe was filled with monkeys shaking sand since the big bang, the odds are still incredibly small that it would have come close to happening yet.

Physicists typically would consider a system as having returned to its original configuration if every important macroscopic quantity was the same. So you could get picky and expect the hills and valleys of the sand to look the same.

In a typical physics problem, you would be dealing with atoms and molecules. Molecules of the same type are identical. It does not matter if two such molecules switch places. Like you might not care which grain is on top of the heap.

You might find that shaking sand makes it hot, or grinds the grains into finer pieces.

It is possible, though really unlikely that two broken pieces can stick back together. So if you shook an inconceivably more than $2^{1000}$ shakes, you might get the grains stuck back to something you might consider their original configuration. But that would be like all the grains winding up on the right side. "Possible", but nothing you would ever see. The by far most common thing would be for sand to be finely ground.

Hot sand cools off if you wait, and the heat has some place to go. Back into your hands, for example.

Comment: so you mean my intuative thinking is false and this is "possible" with the probability of 1 out of 2^1000 which is a number my brain can not imagine how big it is

Comment: Yes. Mine can't either.

Comment: why did you mention the "hot and cool" things, the heat goes to my hands...?

Comment: It is an important part of being in the same state. The question you asked comes up in thermodynamics and statistical mechanics. These subjects are all about heat.

Comment: ok, maybe I am not concerned about the heat right now. "original configuration is nothing more than all the blue grains are on the left and all the red grains are on the right".

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to arrange b blue grains of sand and r red grains of sand is:

(r+b)!/r!b!

Suppose you have 50 grains or red and blue sand each. The number of ways to arrange the sand is ~ 10^29. If you shook the sand once a second, it may take at least 10^25 years before the initial state reappears and that's for only 100 grains of sand. For a million grains the number is inconceivably large.

Comment: yes, I understand the formula, I understand the odd being 1/n (n is very very...very large). But it is still difficult to think if you shake it well for a very long long....long time, some day, it will separate to red and blue parts.